# responsive padding with percentages - css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am unable to figure out, how do we achieve responsive fluidic layout. I kind of figured out it is extremely difficult with `pixels px`. But how is it other wise possible.

I am for example trying a simple thing. Trying to right align two different rows across all devices. Example [here](http://www.bootply.com/mYzW6A4IbN)

I want the `About Us` text and `Some randon text` to be right aligned across all devices. Currently I have to set padding-right in multiple multiple queries(more than 5 or 6). But how is it otherwise possible with `%ages` or any other trick.

> Note: Open the example in tablet mode by shriking the web page. I have currently applies visible-sm class.

Comment: I can't see anything in the previews?

Comment: me neither, all previews are blank

Comment: Note: Open the example in tablet mode by shrinking the web page. I have currently applies visible-sm class.